# Can't create GL buffers with queueEvent

Tags: android, opengl-es

When i try to initialize my model in the `onDrawFrame()` method it's all ok, the buffers are created and then the model is rendered in the right way.
The problem is that when i try to do this initialization in another point using the metod `queueEvent` the code gets executed but the buffers are not created, the strange thing is that i'm executing the code in the OpenGL thread.

This is the code:

```
public synchronized void init() {
    int[] tempVbo = new int[1];
    int[] tempIbo = new int[1];

    vertexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexArray.length * FLOAT_SIZE).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertexArray);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    indicesBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indicesArray.length * SHORT_SIZE).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
    indicesBuffer.put(indicesArray);
    indicesBuffer.position(0);

    GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, tempVbo, 0);
    GLES20.glGenBuffers(1, tempIbo, 0);

    if(tempVbo[0] > 0 && tempIbo[0] > 0) {
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tempVbo[0]);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer.capacity()*FLOAT_SIZE, vertexBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, tempIbo[0]);
        GLES20.glBufferData(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer.capacity()*SHORT_SIZE, indicesBuffer, GLES20.GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GLES20.glBindBuffer(GLES20.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    } else {
        Log.e("ENG_MODEL","Errore creazione buffer modello: VBO=" + tempVbo[0] + " IBO=" + tempIbo[0]);
    }
    Log.d("ENG_MODEL","VBO=" + tempVbo[0] + " IBO=" + tempIbo[0]);
    vbo = tempVbo;
    ibo = tempIbo;
}
```

I think this is something regarding thread synchronization, isn't it? Or I'm using `queueEvent` in the wrong way?